# Need help printing a dynamically allocated linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list, dynamic-programming

```
typedef struct Word {
    char** translations;
    struct Word* next;
} Word;

typedef struct {
    char** languages;
    int numOfLanguages;
    Word* wordList;
} Dictionary;

void printWordList(Word* wordlist, int numOfLanguages)
{
    Word* currentWord = wordlist;
    int i = 0;
    while (currentWord != NULL)
    {
        for (i=0; i < numOfLanguages; i++)
        {
            printf("%s", currentWord->translations[i]);
            if (i < numOfLanguages - 1)
                putchar(',');
        }
        putchar('\n');
        currentWord = currentWord->next;
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Hey, I have a program that's a dynamically allocated dictionary that works like this:

Choose a dictionary:

1. English,Spanish,French
2. English,Hebrew
3. Spanish,English

   ```
   1
   ```

Enter a word in English,Spanish,French:

```
Thank_you,Gracias,Merci
```

The word has been added successfully!

Later I use the function above, printWordList, to try and print all the words (and their translations, Thank_you,Gracias,Merci counts as one, with Gracias and Mercy being in the translations array)

The function works perfectly when there's only one word and translations, but if I add another word to the list, it enters an endless loop and still only prints the first word.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mre] to show us. The  root cause of the problem might be in the code you don't show us.

Comment: If you wrote the program this should just be a matter of finding out what you were thinking at the time you wrote it. Did you make comments in your code that you didn't show us?

Comment: I'm writing it right now, is there anything that isn't clear? I'd be happy to explain the idea or add relevant comments

Comment: @Shakshouk yes, there is a lot of thing that are not clear, for instance we don't know how you call `printWordList` and we don't know if the list is created correctly in the first place. Please [edit] and show a [mcve], this may require some work for you.

Comment: you need to share us how you created the list of Word objects. As such, the `printWordList` function you shown above will not go for endless loop, unless you made a mistake in filling the `next` value for the last node.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran that actually was my problem! Checked how the list was actually created and found the bug. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: welcome, for benefits of others, I posted as answer, you could accept it.

Comment: For future questions, please read the links presented in my first comment! That will save time for both you and us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is, the `printWordList` function you posted above will not go for endless loop, unless you made a mistake in filling the `next` value for the `last` node.